# How to validate 2 Laravel fields in a NAND way

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm looking for a solution to the following case: my controller action receives 2 variables, however they must exclude eachother. So you can pass either 1 of them or none.

The following truth table arises (NAND):

```
| A | B | Result |
|---|---|--------|
| 0 | 0 |   1    |
| 0 | 1 |   1    |
| 1 | 0 |   1    |
| 1 | 1 |   0    |
```

(say `A` equals `points` and `B` equals `coupon`).

```php
// MyController.php
$this->validate($request, [
    'points' => '',
    'coupon' => ''
]);
```

I've tried some solutions like `nullable|required_without:field_name` but those seem to result in an XOR, which means you must pass at least 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to create a new rule called `without:field1,field2`:

```php
Validator::extend('without', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, \Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {
    foreach($parameters as $compare) {
        // Check if the given parameters are filled in, if so we return `false`.
        if($validator->validateRequired(null, array_get($validator->getData(), $compare))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No `without` parameters have been found, validation successful.
    return true;
});

// Replace the error message placeholders.
Validator::replacer('without', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, \Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {
    $attributes = [];
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $attributes[$key] = $validator->getDisplayableAttribute($value);
    }
    return str_replace(':values', implode(' / ', $attributes), $message);
});
```

Next, add a translation to `resources/lang/en/validation.php`:

```php
    'without'              => 'The :attribute may not be set with :values',
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'points' => 'nullable|without:coupon',
    'coupon' => 'nullable|without:points'
]);
```

(you may add multiple parameters like `without:coupon,user_id`)

Which makes sure that:

- Passing `points`and `coupon` together results in a validation error
- Passing a single one of them is OK
- Passing neither of them is OK

Comment: You could also short down your validation closure by returning the negation of the if condition.

Comment: @mdexp doesnt look like it since I am using it in a loop

Comment: You're right, I was on mobile and missed out the foreach.